# Applying machine learning to cache algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

I have an application that receives ~10k of requests per day; each request has multiple parameters and goes through a pipeline with multiple steps and they finish in about 1 hour.
Let's say the requests are like `bake_cake [flavor=chocolate] [topping1=strawberry] [topping2=cream]`

Given a history of requests from previous days, is there a ML framework that can help me predict the "100 most like requests to arrive today" so I can cache their results? Or some other similar strategy that can help me delivering part of those requests faster?

Ideally it would be based on how much I gain by delivering faster, how much I lose by processing a request that might not come, etc.; but for now even simpler algorithms could be of much help since currently there's no optimization.

Comment: I agree that you should start with simpler approaches. Why not simply start with calculating the X% most common requests from the previous days and cache their results? Then measure any improvements and go forward.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to validate your assumptions based on data driven analysis**

- Types of requests received on a day
- Types of requests received on a holiday
- Pattens for different times (Morning / Evening / Night)
- Seasonality / Monthly / Weather based patterns

**Post Analysis**

- Do you see correlation from Data & patterns
- Do you see correlation from Data & Location
- Do you see correlation from Data & Age / Gender / Locality

**ML Models**

- Do you see correlation from Data & patterns
- With the variables we can identity and model a forecast algo

**ML Model is not the start. It is the outcome of detailed data and domain driven analysis**